# What is AggregateCatalog?

Tags: c#, .net, mef, catalog, system.componentmodel

What is [`AggregateCatalog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.aggregatecatalog.aspx)? What does it mean when you construct a `new AggregateCatalog()`? What does it mean when you add assemblies to the catalog, eg `catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(someAssembly))`? Other than assemblies what can you add to the catalog? any general knowledge related to this would be helpful, too (I'm a total noob)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`AggregateCatalog` in MEF basically allows you to collect multiple extension catalogs. When you call `new AggregateCatalog()`, you are basically instantiating a new catalog collection (not necessarily populated) that can contain multiple instances of ComposablePartCatalog, which can contain multiple parts.

Consider it a class that helps you collect parts from multiple sets.

Assemblies are just a way to push parts to the calling application. You can pass parts directly from inside the existing assembly.

For more information about catalogs, I would recommend reading [this](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20Catalogs).

Comment: Would you mind contrasting that to the ModuleCatalog.  They appear to do the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

Mef has a small learning curve - go thru the docs at mef.codeplex.com atleast once. Or try screencasts if you're really pressed for time.

The idea is that a catalog is a dictionary of exported parts (objects to be injected) or parts that need imports (that need injected objects).. The catalog can be populated in multiple ways (hence [the diff Catalog derivations](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20Catalogs&referringTitle=Guide)) -- from a Directory (all asm in a dir) or a Specific assembly.

Next you can create a composite catalog e.g. you want to create a single dictionary that contains all exported objects from DirA and from this specific assembly lying in DirB. In this case, you can create individual catalogs and then a composite catalog which merges the two. Now you consume this merged dictionary in your code to ask for imports/exports.